# max array keys warning

Tags: php, arrays, max

```
<?php

$articleurl = 'http://m.tonton.com.my/webservices/article/get?uniqueid=6E619732-9501-4106-860C-A20D0016E7F0&includeChildTypes=episode&parents=package_season%2Cpackage_content%2Cprogram&children=1&sortBy=published_date&sortDirection=ASC&compact=0&cache=';
$articlecontent = file_get_contents($articleurl);  
$articlejson = json_decode($articlecontent, true);
print_r($articlejson);
echo '<br/>';
$arr = $articlejson['data']['children'];
$max = max(array_keys($arr));
for ($i=0; $i<=$max;++$i)
{
$articleid[$i] = $articlejson['data']['children'][$i]['uniqueId'];
$mediaid[$i] = $articlejson['data']['children'][$i]['version_viostream_id']['default'];
$resources[$i] = 'http://m.tonton.com.my/webservices/media/getProgressiveResources?articleid='.$articleid[$i].'&mediaid='.$mediaid[$i].'&token=e30f4268-0d23-30a4-c9b8-8afd715665b6&cache=&manifestMode=progressive';
$mediacontent[$i] = file_get_contents($resources[$i]);
$mediajson[$i] = json_decode($mediacontent[$i], true);
$array[$i] = $mediajson[$i]['data']['MediaResources'];
$biggest[$i] = max(array_keys($array[$i]));
print_r($biggest[$i]);
```

I am trying to find all largest available array keys but when I run the code, I get the error:

```
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 21  

Warning: max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 21
```

Comment: it looks that $articlejson['data']['children'] value is not there. print this $articlejson['data']['children'] and check his value

Comment: I mean the error is on the part "$array[$i] = $mediajson[$i]['data']['MediaResources'];
$biggest[$i] = max(array_keys($array[$i]));"

Comment: and indent your code for (better) readability! and use the php tag for more colors!

Comment: if you use print_r() or var_dump() on $mediajson and/or $array, you will see their content and dimensions and can go from there. i assume the JSON from this site is not what you expected. put it a check or so before

Comment: print_r() shows the expected result. I think the problem is on max() and array_keys()